# how to return \ retrieve a result from node.js module that does query to mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, module, return

I want to pass a result from mysql query to the level above...

I have this module: **mySQLconnect.js**:

```
var connection = require('mysql').createConnection({
  host : 'localhost',
  user : 'admin',
  password : ''
});

exports.querySelect = querySelect;

function querySelect(query){
    var result = connection.query(query, function(err, rows){
                           return (rows[0]);
                 });
    return result;
}
```

and when I call this function from outside, let's say from **app.js**:

```
var DBconnector = require('mySQLconnect');    
var result = DBconnector.querySelectUser("SELECT * FROM TB_USERS");
```

but the result I get is something else - it's an object from mysql.js module that's been received from:

> connection.query(query, function(err, rows)

it has: **_resultSet =null**, and unreachable  **_results =[Array]**

so it's no good...

I checked in [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) website, but didn't find what's **connection.query** returns.

any ideas how can I pass the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrapping an asynchronous call to the DB with a procedural function – a common mistake for nodejs beginners coming from a procedural language like PHP.

You can simplify your `mySQLconnect.js` module to the following:

```
var connection = require('mysql').createConnection({
  host : 'localhost',
  user : 'admin',
  password : ''
});

exports.querySelect = connection.query;
```

And then consume it thusly:

```
var DBconnector = require('mySQLconnect');
DBconnector.querySelect("SELECT * FROM TB_USERS", function (err, rows) {
  console.log(err || rows);
});
```

I would read up on callbacks, anonymous functions, and asynchronous flow patterns to help you wrap your head around this new style of coding. Good luck!